# Different Persistent Menu for each Messenger Bot user

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Could I, for example, set different languages or different menu options for each user? I did't find such example in Facebook Documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no.
I ran into the same problem 2 weeks ago, and I got this response from Facebook:

> Unfortunately, there is no way to set local for now. This is working as intended but the team will keep your feedback in mind for their next milestones. Hope this helps.

Comment: How did you contact the Facebook team? I have found a lot of bugs and I'm not able to report them